# implementing a binary search tree from a String in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that sorts a String of numbers in ascending order using a BST and print the sorted String as text, but I can't seem to suss out why it isn't functioning properly. When I try to use a StringBuilder to build the String from the tree, it seems as if the tree is empty. I originally thought my problem was with the addNode() method I'd written below:

```
public static TreeNode addNode(TreeNode root,char token){
    if (root == null){
        root = new TreeNode(token);
        return root;
    } else if (root.value >= token) {
            root.left = addNode(root.left, token);
        } else {
            root.right = addNode(root.right, token);
        }
    System.out.println(root);
    return root;
}
```

The value for token and the TreeNode are being pulled from this method that reads the String:

```
public static TreeNode translateString(String tokenize){
    TreeNode r = new TreeNode();

    for(int i=0; i < tokenize.length(); i++){
        char token = tokenize.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(token);

    if (Character.isDigit(token)){
       r = addNode(r, token);
    } else if (token == ' ') {
        continue;
    }    
}   
return r;    
}
```

I originally thought that my problem was with the addNode() method, but if I trace what I *think* it's doing it seems to make sense. However, when it prints the output String I'm not getting any values. Any changes I make to the addNode() method don't seem to work, so I'm thinking now that the problem lies with the translateString() method. I've been stuck on this for several hours now and I'm not sure where to go from here. Any fresh eyes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Use a debugger to see the tree at the end of `translateString` and see what is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem you have is this innocent-looking line:

```
TreeNode r = new TreeNode();
```

By doing this, you're skipping the `null` logic in `addNode()`.  Instead you're making your root be a node with a character value of zero, which is not a printable character.  I think you may want something like this instead:

```
TreeNode r = null;
```